# Is there any way where I can remove custom validations in HTML and add alerts?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to remove custom validations in HTML that occur with "required" attribute in the form. I do want the validations but I want to introduce "alerts" for the inputs.

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <span>Search_word</span>
    <input type="text" required></input>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Frequency</span>
    <select required>
      <option disabled selected value></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Even when I am setting alerts with onlick() method on both, they are coming up twice. If I set up alert only on form, then It's not coming up for the dropdown option. And I am not able to figure out how to remove the custom validations. Is there a way I can turn them to alerts?

Comment: You can try adding javascript code inside script tags of HTML file for adding alerts.

Comment: I am making my form in javascript itself using innerHTML. Will it work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what your code actually looks like. Note that `</input>` is invalid HTML; the `input` element is empty and therefore does not take an end tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use classes on HTML to listen the event on JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <span>Search_word</span>
    <input type="text" class="required"></input>
  </div>

<div>
  <span>Frequency</span>
  <select class="required">
    <option disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="search">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('search').onclick = function changeContent() {

  var requireds = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
  var error = 0;

  for (var i = 0, len = requireds.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (requireds[i].value == "") {
      var error = error + 1;
    }
  }

  if (error > 0){
    if (error == 1) {
      alert("There is a required field to inform");
    } else  {
      alert("There are requireds fields to inform");
    }
  } else {

    // ....

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to keep the HTML validation and introduce a alert message, you can use in HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <span>Search_word</span>
    <input type="text" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter the search word here'); alert('You have to enter a search word');"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  </div>

<div>
  <span>Frequency</span>
  <select class="required" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Select a frequency'); alert('You have to select a frequency');"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
    <option disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="search">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer removes the existing required validations, but the question seeks to keep them.

Comment: Yes. I want to remove custom HTML browser-specific validations but want to keep my own (in the form of alerts)

Comment: Hey @JohnathaRelvas your intial code worked!! I was confused for a while but it works as I was expecting! Thank you so much. Should have tried handling it in javascript. Thank you. I needed to remove the custom validation. It's really interesting how it can be handled without "novalidate" in the form.